# Getting Siri remote touch pad events Apple TV

Tags: tvos

Can anyone please specify how to get the touch actions on Trackpad on Siri remote? I am able to get the Menu, PlayPause button press etc, but not able to get the actions on the TouchPad.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the gesture that you want to recognize in the touchpad. A ton of gestures can be triggered from up there: taps, clicks, directional taps, directional clicks, swipes, long tap, long click, double tap, etc...

You might find the following project interesting, it is a simple playground project with a single UIViewController detecting and logging most of the gesture available via Siri Remote:

https://github.com/dcordero/FunWithGestures